# System of ODEs and DAE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Let us consider the following system of ODEs:
$$
y' = f(y,z),\quad
z' = g(y,z),\quad
y(0) = y_0,\;z(0)=z_0
$$
and the following one:
$$
y' = f(y,z),\quad
0 = g(y,z), \quad y(0) = y_0.
$$
$f$ and $g$ can be nonlinear by $y$ and they are linear by $z$.
Where can I find results about convergence of the solution of the first system to the solution of the second system?